# jquery jscrollpane - scrollbars not working in existing divs when creating new jscrollpane divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jscrollpane

I am using jquery.uploadfile.min.js to upload multiple files and any time I upload a file a create a div of jscrollpane class. The problem is only in the last created div the scrollbars are moving, in the others created before the scrollbars are like dead. When I print in the console a line to check if the 'jsp-scroll-y' function is working I don't get any reaction in the "old" divs...

This is my javascript/jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{   
var settings = {
    url: "/ievo/readimportedlogs",
    method: "POST",
    allowedTypes:"json",
    fileName: "myfile",
    multiple: true,
    reinitialise: function(s)
    {
        s = $.extend({}, this, s);
        initialise(s);
    },  
    onSuccess:function(files,data,xhr)
    {
        var info=[];
        info=data.split('*');
        $("#status").html("<font color='green'>Upload is success</font>");
        var content = $('#import-usb-result').html();
        if (content!="") content+="<br>";
        $('#import-usb-result').html(content+info[0]);
        $('#save_usb_import_canvas').css('display','block');            

           $(".scroll-pane").each(function() {
               $(this).jScrollPane({     
                   showArrows: false,
                    maintainPosition: true,
                    autoReinitialise:true
                });

            //I also tried with...
            /*
            var pane=$(this).jScrollPane();
            var api=pane.data("jsp");
            api.reinitialise();
            */

            //and also...

            /*var apis = $zz(".scroll-pane").map(function() {
                return $zz(this).data("jsp");
            }).get();*/

            // Call an API method for each element
            /*for (var i = 0, api; api = apis[i]; i++) {
                console.log('#1 scroll-pane N APIs', this,"number="+i);
                $zz("#logs-"+i).jScrollPane();
                api.reinitialise();
            }*/


        });     

    },
    onError: function(files,status,errMsg)
    {       
        $("#status").html("<font color='red'>Upload is Failed</font>");
        $('#save_usb_import_canvas').css('display','none');
    }
}


$("#multiplelogsuploader").uploadFile(settings);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Incredible I only needed to do this:

change:
$('#import-usb-result').html(content+info[0]);

to:

$('#import-usb-result').append(info[0]);